# Seleccionar registros jqgrid de diferentes paginas

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Tengo el siguiente Grid en JavaScript utilizando Jqgrid

```
 gridpolizassininventario.jqGrid({
             datatype: 'json',
            url: __appurl + 'obtenerpolizassininventario',
            colNames: ['id', 'Número Proveedor','Póliza', 'Folio Fiscal', 'Importe', 'Tipo cobro/pago', 'Fecha Creación', 'Concepto',
            'Fecha pago', 'Referencia', 'Estatus Póliza', 'Estatus Contabilidad'],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    index: 'id',
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'Proveedor',
                    index: 'Proveedor',
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'NumPoliza',
                    index: 'NumPoliza',
                    width: 180
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'Numfactura',
                    index: 'Numfactura',
                    width: 770
                },
                {
                    name: 'PagoProveedor',
                    index: 'PagoProveedor',
                    width: 300
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'DescTipoCobro',
                    index: 'DescTipoCobro',
                    width: 550
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'FechaElabora',
                    index: 'FechaElabora',
                    width: 280
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'Concepto',
                    index: 'Concepto',
                    width: 1300
                },
                {
                    name: 'FechaPago',
                    index: 'FechaPago',
                    width: 250
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'Referencia',
                    index: 'Referencia',
                    width: 400
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'Cancelada',
                    index: 'Cancelada',
                    width: 340
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'Pagada',
                    index: 'Pagada',
                    width: 400
                }
            ],
            pager: pagerpolizassininventario,
            height: 330,
            width: 1700,
           
            onSelectRow: function (id, check, e) {
                
                
            },
            loadComplete : function (e) {
                if (e.rows == null)
                {
                    _app.showMessage(11); // No hay registros a mostrar
                    $("#btn-imprimir").hide();
                }
            },
            
            
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
            caption: '',
            sortname: "FechaElabora",
            sortorder: "desc",
            multiselect: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            altRows: false,
            gridview: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            
            loadError: function(xhr) {
                application.processAjaxRequestError(xhr);
            }
            
        });
```

El problema es que suponiendo un escenario en que hay mas de 1 pagina en el grid, selecciono un registro de la pagina uno, me voy a la pagina dos para seleccionar otro registro pero en ese momento se perdió el primer registro de la pagina uno, hay alguna manera de mantener la seleccion de los registros en Jqgrid al cambiar de pagina? al regresar a la primera pagina, el registro seleccionado se pierde, necesito poder seguir manteniendo los datos seleccionados sin importar si estan en diferentes paginas del grid

Comment: ¿Y bien? ¿Has logrado solucionar el problema con las respuestas que se te han dado?

Answer (score 0):

Solo es necesario declarar un array vacio al generar el grid por ejemplo "codigosSeleccionados", ademas agregar dos funciones una para guardar los seleccionados "fnSaveSelected" en la funcion del jqgrid "onSelectRow" y otra para agregar los ids seleccionados "fnCheckRows" en funcion del jqgrid "gridComplete"

```js
codigosSeleccionados=[];
gridpolizassininventario.jqGrid({
             datatype: 'json',
            url: __appurl + 'obtenerpolizassininventario',
            colNames: ['id', 'Número Proveedor','Póliza', 'Folio Fiscal', 'Importe', 'Tipo cobro/pago', 'Fecha Creación', 'Concepto',
            'Fecha pago', 'Referencia', 'Estatus Póliza', 'Estatus Contabilidad'],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    index: 'id',
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'Proveedor',
                    index: 'Proveedor',
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'NumPoliza',
                    index: 'NumPoliza',
                    width: 180
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'Numfactura',
                    index: 'Numfactura',
                    width: 770
                },
                {
                    name: 'PagoProveedor',
                    index: 'PagoProveedor',
                    width: 300
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'DescTipoCobro',
                    index: 'DescTipoCobro',
                    width: 550
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'FechaElabora',
                    index: 'FechaElabora',
                    width: 280
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'Concepto',
                    index: 'Concepto',
                    width: 1300
                },
                {
                    name: 'FechaPago',
                    index: 'FechaPago',
                    width: 250
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'Referencia',
                    index: 'Referencia',
                    width: 400
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'Cancelada',
                    index: 'Cancelada',
                    width: 340
                }
                ,
                {
                    name: 'Pagada',
                    index: 'Pagada',
                    width: 400
                }
            ],
            pager: pagerpolizassininventario,
            height: 330,
            width: 1700,
           
            gridComplete: function(){       
                fnCheckRows(); 
            },
            onSelectRow: function (id, check, e) {
                fnSaveSelected(id, check);
            },

            loadComplete : function (e) {
                if (e.rows == null)
                {
                    _app.showMessage(11); // No hay registros a mostrar
                    $("#btn-imprimir").hide();
                }
            },
            
            
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
            caption: '',
            sortname: "FechaElabora",
            sortorder: "desc",
            multiselect: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            altRows: false,
            gridview: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            
            loadError: function(xhr) {
                application.processAjaxRequestError(xhr);
            }
            
        });

    function fnCheckRows(){               
        for(var x = 0; x < codigosSeleccionados.length; x++){          
            gridpolizassininventario.jqGrid('setSelection',codigosSeleccionados[x].split(',')[0]);   
        }
        
    }
    function fnSaveSelected(rowid, status){
        
        //aqui puedes incluir los campos que necesites del grid en este ejemplo solo se incluye el id
        var keyx = gridpolizassininventario.jqGrid('getCell',rowid,'id');
        var index=jQuery.inArray(keyx, codigosSeleccionados);
        if(status && index < 0) {
            codigosSeleccionados.push(keyx );
            
        } else if(!status && index >= 0)
        {
            codigosSeleccionados.splice(index, 1);       
        }
       
        
        
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé qué jqGrid utilizas. Pero lo más recomendable sería utilizar las últimas versiones de [free-jqGrid](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) porque ya tiene una propiedad (`multiPageSelection: true`) adecuada para esto, además de muchas otras ventajas sobre el jqGrid original.
Puedes ver un ejemplo de cómo funciona tu necesidad en concreto [aquí](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/multiPageSelection.htm)